# Highlight a select option using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a group list as select like that:

```
<select id="groups">

<option value="g1">G1</option>
<option value="g2">G2</option>
<option value="g3">G3</option>

</select>
```

I have a contact list which basically contains:

```
Name = group
============
Casper  G1-G2-G3
Andy    G1-G2
Mark    G2-G3
```

When the user check the `checkbox` for `Casper`and click `Edit` button so `G1-G2 and G3` should be highlighted (Selected) in the group list. When I get the value of the group field in the contact list, all of the three groups come with comma `"G1-G2-G3"`. 
Your help is highly appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips, I believe it's good for you to solve this problem yourself ;)

- Seems that `Casper` belongs to multiple groups, so you should set `multiple="true"` to your `select`
- When you check `Casper`, retrieve the group data associated with him, say `["g1", "g2", "g3"]`. Loop over this list, and set each option with the value to `selected`.
- If you want to support IE6, you need also add a class, say `selected` to the `selected` option.
- The CSS rule `{ option.selected: background: yellow}` will do the trick.
- If you only target on modern browser, `option[selected]{ xxx }` works well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I select Casper and click Edit button, I will get " G1-G2-G3" as a text only with comma

Comment: Then using `"G1-G2-G3".toLowerCase().split("-")` to get that list.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the edit button assign the selected attribute to the options then use css to style it.

```
option[selected] { background: #f00; }
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I guess there is a checkbox for `Casper` that when clicked calls the following function:

```
function(groupstring) {
// groupstring is something like "G1-G2"

    var groups = groupstring.split("-");
    var options = document.getElementById("groups").options;
    for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        opt.defaultSelected = groups.indexOf(opt.value) > -1;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure whether you want to use the `selected` or the `defaultSelected` property. Note that your select should have `multiple` set to true (`<select id="groups" multiple>`).